# jQuery selector: excluding combination of classnames

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I have a list with this information:

```
<li class="me">my name goes here</li>
<li class="settings">some info here</li>
<li class="me settings">some other here</li>
<li class="me">my address goes here</li>
```

When the user opens the page, the items that have the .me classname (just the .me classname **only**) must be highlighted:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.me').effect('highlight',{color:'#FFFFFF'},3000);
});
```

The problem is that the third list item ("me settings") is also being highlighted. How can I exclude the items that:

- don't have the .me classname
- do have the .me classname combined with **any** other classname

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('li[class="me"]').effect('highlight', {color:'#FFFFFF'}, 3000);
});
```

where we select `li` which attribute `class` is exactly `me`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the negation selector .not()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.me').not('[class*=" "]').effect('highlight',{color:'#FFFFFF'},3000);
});
```

Comment: i should clarify, that the selector has to exclude -any- other classname, not just .settings

Comment: @andufo perhaps replacing not('.settings') with not('[class*=" "]') that means not spaces in class, so if you separate clases by space, this will exclude all joins .me + any

Comment: Yest, it works. See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CZmu8/ I edit my answer with correct solution

Comment: You may as well condense this to `li[class="me"]`, but it doesn't account for space-padded attributes like `<li class=" me">`. Not that that would matter in practice, though (but maybe it does)...